# How to prepend to an HTML element?

Tags: python, html

How do I prepend to an HTML `div` using Python using element IDs?

For example, if I have the following HTML code in a file called "test.html":

```
<div id="insertHere">
</div>
```

And I want to insert the following line `<li> Item 1 </li>` into the div element with id "insertHere." So I want the resulting markup to look like this:

```
<div id="insertHere">
   <li> Item 1 </li>
</div>
```

How do I do this in Python? I tried doing the following:

```
myfile = open('test.html', 'w')
myfile.write('<li> Item 1 </li>')
myfile.close()
```

but the problem with `myfile.write` is that it does not give me an option to specify to place the list item in the div with id "insertHere."

I suppose this would be similar to the `prepend()` function in Javascript.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. A question like this is considered too broad here - please read [ask] and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users . You should understand that only Javascript will run in-browser normally, and you will need to know how to read a file from the disk (assuming that's where you want it to come from). There are libraries you can use to parse HTML, but you should make sure you know the language fundamentals first.

Comment: Also, in the future, please only tag languages that are relevant to your intended solution, not to things you are referring to in order to explain the problem.

Comment: @Karl Knechtel I made edits to the question to specify what I did, so I hope the question is no longer too broad. But I don't think what you said solves what I need, I am not trying to parse HTMl from a browser, I am trying to edit a local HTML file with Python.

Comment: Generally speaking, you need to read the existing file contents, prepare the desired resulting output and write it back. Files are not random-access, and cannot just be inserted into arbitrarily (because everything after the "insertion point" would have to be moved forward). This is not a Python thing, it's a how-computers-work thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Importing 
with open("doc.html", "r") as file:
  html = file.read() 


# Changing 

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

myId = soup.find(id='insertHere')

new_tag = soup.new_tag("li")
new_tag.append("Item 1")

myId.append(new_tag)

html = str(soup)

# Saving

with open("doc.html", "w") as file:
  file.write(html)
```

output:

```
<div id="insertHere">
<li>Item 1</li>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your helpful answer! My html is actually in a separate file called "test.html." So instead of doing `soup = BeautifulSoup(html)`, would I do `soup = BeautifulSoup(test.html)`?

Comment: Nope, use ```open```, I'll update the answer

Comment: Thank you so much! Really appreciate it.